# Obtaining dynamically created element

Tags: jquery, dom

Ok, I am dynamically creating hidden input fields as follows:

```
$("<input type='hidden' id=pid'"+postid+"-title name='posts["+postid+"][title]' value='' />" +
  "<input type='hidden' id=pid'"+postid+"-body name='posts["+postid+"][body]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id=pid'"+postid+"' class='category' name='posts["+postid+"][category]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id=pid'"+postid+"' class='author' name='posts["+postid+"][author]' value='' />"
).appendTo("#datatable");
```

In order to facilitate debugging, I changed the id of the title input to in clude its class (which is title). So it seems as if I should be able to access it with the code `$('#pid'+id+'-title')`. This, however, is not the case. Rather, the result of using `$("#pid"+id+"-title")toSource()` is `({context:({}), selector:"#pid0-title"})`. 0, by the way, is the correct ID.

I feel I must be missing something obvious about JQuery and dynamic elements. What are the reasons that I apparently cannot find my object?

Comment: you are doubling the id of category and author, but this is not the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in this way is more clear and orderly:

```
var createInputs = function(postid) {

    var 
        input = $('<input type="hidden" value="" />'),
        createInput = function(id, type) {
            return input.clone()
                    .addClass(type)
                    .attr('id', 'pid' + id + '-' + type)
                    .attr('name', 'posts[' + id + '][' + type + ']');
        };

    $()
        .add(createInput(postid, 'title'))
        .add(createInput(postid, 'body'))
        .add(createInput(postid, 'category'))
        .add(createInput(postid, 'autor'))
        .appendTo('#datatable');

};    

createInputs(1);

console.log($('#datatable').html());
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/adescalzo/DtNJ7/)

Answer (score 1):

You have quotes in your ids, also you have duplicate ids, neither of which are valid. Please just use a unique ID with acceptable characters (starts with alpha, can include numeric and underscore and possibly a few others which I forget)

```
$("<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-title' name='posts["+postid+"][title]' value='' />" +
  "<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-body' name='posts["+postid+"][body]' value='cccc' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-category' class='category' name='posts["+postid+"][category]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-author' class='author' name='posts["+postid+"][author]' value='' />").appendTo("#datatable");


 alert($("#pid1-body").val());
```

The above works in jQuery and I can select by ID and get the value as shown, the apostrophes in your ids were killing the code.

Comment: valid characters for identifiers [are](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters).

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are not getting the value for the `ID` attribute due to a misplaced 'single quote' on all of them.

See this [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/wtZ3Z/) Example!

**Adapt your code to this:**

```
$("<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-title' name='posts["+postid+"][title]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"-body' name='posts["+postid+"][body]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"' class='category' name='posts["+postid+"][category]' value='' />" +
"<input type='hidden' id='pid"+postid+"' class='author' name='posts["+postid+"][author]' value='' />"
).appendTo("#datatable");
```

*The selection of the element should go without any problems now.*

---

**Note:**
As mentioned by @Jeff Watkins, you shouldn't have duplicated `ID`s on the `document`.

The `input.category` and the `input.author` have the same `ID`.

See the relevant [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors), where it reads:

> ...an ID attribute can be used to uniquely identify its element.